# Eliminar etiquetas <script> y codigo como window.onload de un String

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Tengo un problema, estoy recuperado contenido de una pagina web haciendo uso de

`product.querySelector('div#productspecification').innerHTML` desde NodeJS

Esto si funciona, me devuelve el contenido que este dentro de ese div, con ese id. el problema es que ve devuelve dos `<div>` con etiquetas javascript que no puedo almacenar en la base de datos.
Estas son los `<div>` con etiquetas javascript:

```
<div class="col-md-1" data-hideonprint="true">
   <script type="text/javascript" src="/Site/Scripts/CNet.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      window.onload = function () {
      handleCnetLogos('https://ws.cnetcontent.com','https:                 //ws.cnetcontent.com','c7b4bb94','KONICA%20MINOLTA','8938613','MX01@@6030@@10@@','es_MX','1','1x4',false);
      }
   </script>
  <div id="ccslogos">
  </div>
</div>
```

como puedo quitar o remover las etiquetas **javascript** y contenidos como el **window.onload**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para eliminar tanto los `script` como su contenido, utiliza una expresión regular:

```javascript
const cadenaSinScript = cadenaConScript.replace(/<script.*>.*<\/script>/ims, " ");
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, me funciono perfectamente.

Comment: Super! Que estés bien.